# Return a function with signature String -> String from another function

Tags: function, haskell

I'm programming in Haskell and have the following type.

```
type Phonebook = String -> String
```

Now I have to create a function that returns an empty Phonebook, so

```
emptyPhonebook :: Phonebook
emptyPhonebook = ???
```

But what is an empty Phonebook?

I mean it has to be an "empty" function, but how do I write that in Haskell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I does not have to be an empty funtion, it has to be a `String->String` function, even `id` would do

```
emptyPhonebook :: Phonebook
emptyPhonebook  = \_ -> ""
```

Take a look at this [running example](http://rextester.com/QKJ11913):

Answer (score 7):

There is no such thing as an empty function.

The question is, what should your phonebook return for names that aren't in the phone book?
If this is a learning exercise, you could just return an empty string - as in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41692676/812149).

However, a better definition of your phonebook would be:

```
type Phonebook = String -> Maybe String
```

Then your function becomes:

```
emptyPhoneBook :: Phonebook
emptyPhoneBook _ = Nothing
```

This is like using nullable types in languages like C#; the `Maybe` says that your value can either be a String, or `Nothing`.

For completeness, I should add that if `Maybe String` contains a string value, its value will be preceded by the keyword `Just`.
For example, if the String in question was "Judie", the value would be `Just "Judie"` rather than merely "Judie".
The `Just` is because the value is of type `Maybe String`, not of type `String`.